# hello how can i check if a song is in a user's favorites list

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I set up a feature to add songs to favorites for my song and lyrics project, I did this with a django rest framework api and javascript fetch but I did a check in my template to savor if a song is in the favorites so that I can delete it but it doesn't work the songs are duplicated in the favorites please help. how can i proceed?

favorite models:

```
class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song = models.ForeignKey('main.Song', on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='favorites')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    data=models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

user models

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    
    #favorite_songs = models.ManyToManyField('main.Song', blank=True, related_name='favorited_by')
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

song models

```
class Song(models.Model):
    class Category(models.TextChoices):
        VICTORY_SONG = "victory_song"
        WORSHIP = "worship"
        PRAISE = "praise"
        SUPPLICATION = "supplication" 

    category = models.CharField(
        choices=Category.choices, max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Titre")
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Auteur", default="unknown")
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=3000, null=True)
    lyrics = models.TextField(max_length=500000, verbose_name="lyrics")
    date_of_creation = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, verbose_name="année de composittion"
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    music = models.FileField(upload_to="music/", null=True, blank=True)
    logo_music = models.ImageField(default="static/images/mario")
    image = models.ImageField()
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug= models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=50,blank=True)
    

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
    
    
    
    def is_favorite(self ,user):
        return self.favorite_set.filter(user=user).exists()
```

the view and urls of api

```
class FavoritesongView(APIView):
    def get(self , request,product_id):
        try:
            product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
            print('voila le produit demander:',product_id)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f" error in  get favorite {e}")
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_302_FOUND) 
            
  
    def post(self, request , song_id):
           try:
               song = Song.objects.get(id=song_id)
               favorite = Favorite(user=request.user, song=song)
               favorite.save()
               return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
           except Exception as e:
               print(f"ERROR in post request{e}")
               return Response({"error": str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


            
    def delete(self, request, song_id):
           try:
               favorite = Favorite.objects.get(user=request.user, song_id=song_id)
               favorite.delete()
               return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
           except Exception as e:
               print(f"ERROR in delete request{e}")
               return Response({"error":str(e)},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

urls api

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('songs/<int:song_id>/favorite/', FavoritesongView.as_view())
]
```

javaScript file

```
function updateFavoriteButton(songId, isFavorite) {
  const button = document.querySelector(`button[data-song-id="${songId}"]`);
  if (isFavorite) {
    button.textContent = 'Supprimer des favoris';
    button.onclick = () => removeFavorite(songId);
  } else {
    button.textContent = 'Ajouter aux favoris';
    button.onclick = () => addFavorite(songId);
  }
}






javascript
async function addFavorite(songId) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`/api/songs/${songId}/favorite/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken'),
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ song_id: songId }),
        });
        if (response.ok) {
            updateFavoriteButton(songId, true);
            // La favorite a été ajoutée avec succès
        } else {
            // Une erreur s'est produite
            console.log('erreur dans addfavorite');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}

async function removeFavorite(songId) {
  try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/songs/${songId}/favorite/`, {
          method: 'DELETE',
          headers: {
              'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken'),
          },
      });
      if (response.ok) {
          updateFavoriteButton(songId, false);
          // La favorite a été supprimée avec succès
      } else {
          // Une erreur s'est produite
          console.log("l'erreur est dans removefavorite");
      }
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}



function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift();
}
```

html song_list

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/images/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/theme.css/">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"> 
    
   

   
    <title>Lys de Vallée</title>
</head>
{% include 'SearchHeader.html' %}
<body>
  {% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Liste de chansons</h1>
<ul>
    {% for song in songs %}
   <li> <a href="{% url 'lyrics' song.id %}">{{ song.title }}</a></li>
   {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  {% if song.is_favorite %}
    <button onclick="removeFavorite({{ song.id }})">Supprimer des favoris</button>
  {% else %}
    <button onclick="addFavorite({{ song.id }})">Ajouter aux favoris</button>
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Connectez-vous pour ajouter aux favoris</a>
{% endif %}


 
 </li>
  
  

    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
<script src="/static/js/favoriteApi.js/"></script> 
<script src="/static/js/sttings.js/"></script> 
<script src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 


</html>
```

I put a boolean field is_favorite for me that I put my condition on it but I did not succeed please help me

Comment: Can you add songlist view

Comment: I already added    
def song_list(request):
    user = request.user
    songs = Song.objects.all()

    return render(request, "main/song_list.html", locals())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use annotate and Exists.

```py
from django.contrib.models import Exists, OuterRef

def song_list(request):
    user = self.request.user
    songs = Song.objects.all().annotate(is_fav=Exists(Favorite.objects.filter(user=user, song=OuterRef("id"))))
    return render(request, "main/song_list.html", context={"songs": songs"})
```

You can chech in template with is_fav attribute